# I'm not able to retrieve values using set get property in 2tier

Tags: c#

I'm not able to retrieve values using `set` nor `get`. Can you tell where I made mistake?

form1.cs// ui tier

```
 bb obj= new bb();
 obj._Pur_Net_Total_Amount="fun";
 method();
```

class2.cs // business tier

```
class bb()  
{
    string Net_Total_Amount = string.Empty;
    public string _Pur_Net_Total_Amount
    {
        get { return Net_Total_Amount; }
        set { Net_Total_Amount = value; }
    }
}
```

form3.cs // business tier

```
    bb obj = new bb();
    textbox1.text=obj._Pur_Net_Total_Amount;//here i'm not getting "fun" string value
```

can anyone help....

Comment: In form3.cs, you have a *different* `bb obj`, which has a *different* `_Pur_Net_Total_Amount`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass variable values between two class in different projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545888/how-to-pass-variable-values-between-two-class-in-different-projects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you created object `obj` and assign a string to its property in `form1.cs`, later you are creating another object with the same name in `form3.cs`, that object has no knowledge of your previous object *(created in `form1`)*.

Having same name in two different places would not get you the same object.

You can pass the object to `form3` from `form1`, see [Passing Values Between Windows Forms c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/passing-values-between-windows-forms-c-sharp)

Comment: @Jana, changing the object name would not do anything, You have too look into the way for passing values between multiple forms. look at the linked question in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new object in the lower code. You do `bb obj = new bb();`, this is a new instance. It is not the same instance as the above one where you set the property.