# how to pass variable values between two classes in different projects

Tags: c#

how to pass variable values between two class in different projects

project1

```
form1.cs// ui tier

      bb obj= new bb();
      cc objc = new cc();
      obj._Pur_Net_Total_Amount="fun";
      objc.method();
```

project2

```
class2.cs // business tier

class bb()  
{
    string Net_Total_Amount = string.Empty;
    public string _Pur_Net_Total_Amount
    {
        get { return Net_Total_Amount; }
        set { Net_Total_Amount = value; }
    }
}
```

project 2

form3.cs // business tier

```
class cc()
{
    bb obj = new bb();
    method()
    {
    textbox1.text=obj._Pur_Net_Total_Amount;//here i'm not getting "fun" strin
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm not able to retrieve values using set get property in 2tier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545004/im-not-able-to-retrieve-values-using-set-get-property-in-2tier)

Comment: Have you added references to your projects?

Comment: You can't have two Web Forms projects in the same solution.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn this is definitely a duplicate as it is the same code and person.

Comment: in that post i dnt mention that different project so only

Comment: Possible duplicate! It's the same guy!

Comment: @Jana do you know the difference between a class and an object?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Yes you can. You can have two WebForms projects in the same solution. They won't interact just like that though.

Comment: @MrLister I should have been more precise, in that you shouldn't have two Web Forms projects in a solution, at least I cannot see there ever being a benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bb object your using in class cc is not the same you instantiate in form1 - you can pass the object to method in class cc to use it.

```
form1.cs// ui tier

bb obj= new bb();
cc objc = new cc();
obj._Pur_Net_Total_Amount="fun";
objc.method(obj);
```

and

```
class cc()
{
  method(bb obj)
  {
    textbox1.text=obj._Pur_Net_Total_Amount;//here i'm not getting "fun" strin
  }
}
```