# How to create shopping cart using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, shopping-cart

Scenario - In form A, user select sample/s and quantity and add it cart button. When you click on the add to cart button, it goes to form B where one could see the selection and then if they want to add more sample, they click go back.

Now I am not sure how to save user selection, because if I go back, it removes all data. I am newbee to this.

Please advise. My code -

form A

```
Form2 screen = new Form2(sample_array, quantity_array);             
screen.ShowDialog();
```

form B

```
void populate_listview(string[] sample_name, string[] qty_amt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lib_name.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] subitems = new string[] { sample_name[i], qty_amt[i] };
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(subitems);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);      

        }     

    }
```

What code should I add so that it saves the current list and then append to new user selection.

Comment: We can't see your screen, and you have not described your problem in enough detail for us to understand what you want. If you don't know how to pass a selection in one form to another form, consult [Passing Values Between Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/).

Comment: I know how to pass values from one form to other. I want to create a add cart feature. Form B is where all the values get displayed and so if a user want to add more values then they must go back form A to select more values. But I don't know how to save previous selection in Form B and append new user selection to it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to use a content presenter inside your page and notify the main page (the one with the cart and all selected items) via Event Publisher!

[image]

You can find details about Content Presenter here :
[Content Presenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and about events here : [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)