# searching using a different form

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have developed a program which save, delete, update, search and the records are displayed on one form(MainForm1). The help I need is to have another form(SearchForm) whereby I can use it for searching only but the information should be displayed on the main form(MainForm1) when I search.

MainForm1- save, delete, update( the records should be displayed here when searching).

SearchForm- searching only here

I have no idea how can i do it.

Comment: Make sure the SearchForm has a reference to the MainForm1. Make public methods on MainForm1 that SearchForm can use to display the result.

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Values Between Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your new form as usual and put your MainForm in the constructor like this:

```
public class SearchForm : Form {
    MainForm m;

    public SearchForm(MainForm _m) {
        InitializeComponent();
        m =_m;
    } 
}
```

Call the new class/form using `new SearchForm(this).Show();` from your MainForm class.

Now set the modifiers of the controls you want to update to public, so you can access them from your SearchForm class using something like `m.TextBox1.Text = "Hello world!`.