# Display Message box on the parent form when child is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application, in which from parent form I open a child form. This child form can be opened from multiple parent forms. But when opened from a specific parent form, I want a message box to display when the child form gets minimized. Basically I want to check the name of the parent form which is an .exe and display the message box. Both child and parent forms are .exe.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I am not able to get the parent .exe name.

Comment: When opening form you can pass current parent form name as parameter. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17836398/1997232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Any(form => form.Name == "<YOUR_CHILD_FORM_NAME>"))
{
    Form tempForm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(form => form.Name == "<YOUR_CHILD_FORM_NAME>");
    if (tempForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        // FORM IS OPEN AND ALSO IN MINIMIZE MODE
    }
    else
    {
        // FORM IS OPEN BUT NOT IN MINIMIZE MODE
    }
}
else
{
    // FORM IS NOT OPEN
}
```

> NOTE

While opening of your child form you must have to set name of your child window like....

```
ChildForm cForm = new ChildForm();
cForm.Name = "<YOUR_CHILD_FORM_NAME>";
cForm.Show();
```