# c# can a new window be assigned to text box but stored in a databse

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am building a record management system that stores data in SQL Database. Im trying to build it in a smaller project then impalement in a larger scale. So far I have 5 textBoxs that are storing data into a database and I can recall a row to populate the textboxes off of a textBox called "ID".

What I want to be able to do is either have a smaller button next to each textbox OR be able to click in the textbox then click a button which shows a secondary window that i can input data. I can make a second window/form that stores data to its own table but how would I make c# know if in one textbox on table1, ID "1", textbox "1" should recall information from table2, ID "1".

This is kinda weird to read maybe I can draw this out better [Diagram of idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbqc5.gif)

I couldn't find to words to search for something like this since I just starting out in C# I don't how to store information for ID"1" and have c# remember that textbox1 has information stored that pertains only to if in another table that can be displayed in a

Comment: You could pass the Id into the secondary window via a parameter in its constructor. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/passing-values-between-windows-forms-c-sharp

Comment: Have you heard of data models? Usually your data is stored in some sort of data model (some object or structure of objects usually in a separate class(es)) and the UI changes the data in this model. That way when you click the save button it uses the data model to save information to the database.

Comment: The biggest question is why are you trying to do this? What do you want to do? Depending on your answer, there might be better/simpler ways to do that. Another question I have is: Are each textbox somehow linked each to a different table? From what I understand, each Textbox will have a button that will link to another table.

Comment: Another question is, what content is going to be shown on the modal form (The secondary window)?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ubsweb8n/

Comment: I will make a quick video of my this program and narrate it. But as far as the lay out, yes and i can construct the forms and make the buttons bring it up. Im at work so it might take me a minute to get something put to geather

Comment: Here is that video http://youtu.be/K3VmrOUrJyE